# Merging Multiple Page InDesign Documents

Tags: adobe-indesign

I worked on a book that was saved in separate InDesign documents. Each file has about 10 - 20 pages.
I want to combine it now to become one big InDesign document.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a Book (via main menu File > New > Book) and then add your multiple InDesign docs to this book. There will be a plus (+) sign in a small window that will pop up after your create your book, and clicking this (+) will let you add individual INDD files to your book.

There are numerous videos and articles online on how to work with this feature so i won't go into much detail, but generally this is what you should be looking for.

Hope this helps!